# how to make my website fluid?

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I've never done this before. The website I have just built is the second one I have ever built. There is a main container div and a header. I noticed that this simple html/css and js site looks terrible on mobile devices.

When it comes to making the site fluid are there any rules or approaches to make it quick and easy? If I just start changing all set pixel widths to percentages will the elements lose thir alignment in relation to each other? For example, the image in the main image slider is aligned, using pixels, based upon the position of the logo in the header.

Before I get started any pointers would be most appreciated. Here is the site: www.hauswoods.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want your website to be fluid just use percentage instead of pixels.

```
.classname{
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My concern though is losing positioning in relation to other elements. The current pixel widths keep various elements lined up based upon other elements on the site. If only there was a magic line of code that scaled the whole document in a oner

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you look into [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) instead, this will allow you to specify CSS related to different screen sizes. Yes, you could change your website to a liquid/fluid layout but with your current content, getting the slider and images to look right will be a headache.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy approach would be to use a framework like Bootstrap (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

I'm sure some people would argue that you won't learn if you use that (because it will do a lot for you), but I think you can learn by example.

Bootstrap uses progressive enhancement principles to improve UIs and uses something called 'Less' for making CSS a bit more generic (at the expense of some complexity).  Still, you can use whichever bits you like from it.  If you've got a greenfield site it's a good place to start.  It supports fluid layouts and explains to you how your design will degrade on mobile devices with smaller screens.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of good tutorials out there:

http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=199

http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/

http://css-tricks.com/the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/

Answer (score 1):

Below are IMHO some of the best JS-frameworks/html5-templaters that help with what you're trying to achieve. No need to re-invent the wheel.

- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)
- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [CreateJS](http://createjs.com/#!/CreateJS)
- [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/)
- [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)
- [HTML KickStart](http://www.99lime.com/elements/)
- [Montage HTML5 Framework](http://montagejs.org/)
- [SproutCore](http://sproutcore.com/)
- [Zebra](http://zebra.gravitysoft.org/)